# How to show Total Monthly Price on the Quote Template?

Tags: pdf, quote, quote-template

We sell products for a monthly subscription fee and we are using the Quote PDF functionality.

Problem arises when customers purchase different products of different quantities like the examples mentioned below:

**Example 1:**

```
product Name    Sale Price    Quantity    Total Price
______________________________________________________
ProductA        10.00         10          100.00
ProductB        20.00         20          200.00
______________________________________________________

Total Monthly cost(for the first 10 months) : 30.00
Total Monthly cost(after the initial 10 months): 20.00
```

**Example 2:**

```
product Name    Sale Price    Quantity    Total Price
______________________________________________________
ProductA        10.00         10          100.00
ProductB        20.00         10          200.00
______________________________________________________

Total Monthly cost : 30.00
```

Can somebody please suggest me on how to solve this?

**EDIT:**

Here is the screenshot of our current quote template with the Total Monthly Cost(Custom Field on the Quote Object) highlighted and this works only for the 2nd scenario explained above:

[image]

Comment: Is there any more detail you could provide? Any relevant code, maybe a more specific description of your issue? I'm having trouble understanding

Comment: @BrianMansfield I edited the question, Please let me know if you need more details. FYI: We are not using any apex code for this just enabled Quotes and Quote Templates in our org.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you're asking, you'll need to create a custom quote template with a custom controller. I recommend that you install [Simple Quote/Invoice/Order](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001TLtcEAG) from the App Exchange which is a free unmanaged package to use a baseline starting point.

You'll need to copy the code from the controller and create a new custom one with a wrapper class. Use the wrapper class to calculate the before and after monthly costs for your products in addition to your quotes for them. You can use the PDF templates as a guide for creating new templates to use with the custom controller. It's not that you need the unmanaged package to accomplish this. Its a case where it sounds as though it would be helpful to you in getting you started.